# Overlapping instances by turning Monads into Semigroups

Tags: haskell

`Monads` define `Semigroups` via

```
instance Monad m => Semigroup (m a) where
    (<>) = (>>)
```

using FlexibleInstances.

If I wanted to make `Maybe a` into a `Semigroup` in that way I would run
into an Intance overlap, because `Data.Semigroup` defines an

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a)
```

What is the Haskell-Way to resolve something like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The common way in which these problems are solved is with a newtype wrapper.
You wouldn't define an `instance Semigroup (m a)`, but rather

```
newtype WrappedMonad m a = WrappedMonad { getWrappedMonad :: m a }

instance Monad m => Semigroup (WrappedMonad m a) where
    WrappedMonad a <> WrappedMonad b = WrappedMonad (a >> b)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm. I just wish there was a way to hide the instances..